# Screen tear or I don't know what to call it when using chrome

Tags: 14.04, graphics, google-chrome, screen, appearance

I rarely posts question but well this has been bugging me since i started using Ubuntu 14.04, of course previously I was using Win8.1 without any issues.

My screen has a tear when using chrome which looks like dead pixels or what seemed to be tearing when I minimize and maximize back and it actually shifts the screen a little to the right. Sometimes I even have to click a little to the left to be accurate at clicking things.

Here's a screenshot, you could see it clearly vertically down right beside the launcher/docker:

[image: Screenshot]